# Name for numbers of the form $p_{j_1}^{p_{j_n}} p_{j_2}^{p_{j_{n-1}}}\dots p_{j_{n-1}}^{p_{j_2}} p_{j_n}^{p_{j_1}}.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, terminology

Consider the numbers of the form

$$p_{j_1}^{p_{j_n}} p_{j_2}^{p_{j_{n-1}}}\dots p_{j_{n-1}}^{p_{j_2}} p_{j_n}^{p_{j_1}},$$

where $p_{j_1}<\dots<p_{j_n}$ are primes and $n\in\Bbb N$.

The first few examples, from least to greatest, are

$$\begin{align}
2^2&=4,\\
3^3&=27,\\
2^33^2&=72,\\
2^55^2&=800,\\
5^5&=3125.
\end{align}$$

Note that each such number is not squarefree.

Does this sequence have a name? (I doubt it, since it's not on the OEIS.)

Comment: Are you ordering by least to greatest? Maybe fixing $n$ and looking at number of prime factors might be easier, idk.

Comment: I think, nearest to those come the powerful numbers.

Comment: Yes, @Integrand; thank you.

Comment: How so, @Peter?

Comment: @Shaun Each exponent is $2$ or larger, but need not be prime. I just noticed that your numbers are even more special than I first thought. Nevetheless, I am not aware of numbers fitting better to what you invented.

Comment: I think, such numbers are quite rare. Did you count them in $10^k$ - ranges ? Would be interesting.

Comment: Not yet, @Peter. I'm busy all of a sudden. I'll do so tomorrow.

Comment: Is $1$ also allowed , or shall we omit this number ?

Comment: I think we shall omit it (but that's only because I don't see how $1$ fits the definition), @Peter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112123/discussion-between-peter-and-shaun).

Comment: $1$ would be obtained from the empty, $0$-length, list of primes.

Comment: This is now [on the OEIS](https://oeis.org/A334633).